# Android Google Maps talking to Google Maps Enterprise Data?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-earth

Is it possible to switch the Android Google Maps code to utilize custom data provided by a Google Enterprise?

Details:
Google provides an "enterprise" version of its maps service, where you can host your own data. See here:
http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/earth_technical.html

But Android's Maps API has no way of using any alternative data sources other than what is freely available on the web.
http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/index.html

There are other tools like Open Street Maps or AndNav, but here, I need to use Google.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for switching the `MapView` data source, and since it is not open source, there's no obvious way to change it.

You can, however, use `WebView` to embed a standard Web-based Google Maps that could, presumably, come from your "enterprise" edition.

Answer (score 0):

With the new V2 api on android you can set the tile source by providing a custom TileProvider.  I am not familiar with the enterprise offerings, but this should be possible if the tiles are available via a url. The exact implementation will depend on how the tiles are accessed, but here some code to get started:

```
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);

TileOverlayOptions options = new TileOverlayOptions();

options.tileProvider(new UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {
@Override
public URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int z) {
    try {
        String f = "http://yourURL/%d/%d/%d.png";
        return new URL(String.format(f, z, x, y));
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

});

map.addTileProvider(options);