# Specify the server for Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Is there a way to specify the server to connect to with the Google Maps Android API v2?

For instance, I would like to connect to an internal Google Earth Server.

Comment: If you mean for tiles you can write your own TileProvider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you are not able to specify that :) Android uses sockets to connect to its servers and all external SDK interfaces are optimized to GoogleMaps server capabilities.

If you want to use your own map tiles - you can implement you own [TileProvider](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider), so you will be able to provide map tiles from any server you want

[UrlTileProvider](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/UrlTileProvider) is really good example to start with. What you need to do - is to supply right `url` for the map coordinates and Android will download map tile and cache it for you

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be a viable alternative. I've also found out some related questions that point to the same solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973722/images-tile-on-google-map-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459962/android-google-maps-talking-to-google-maps-enterprise-data and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695393/open-street-maps-with-android-google-maps-api-v2